# Code problems upgrading IronPython from 2.0 to 2.7

Tags: c#, ironpython

I just found out our old IronPython DLLs are not compatible with .NET 4.0. I have removed the old references from our project and added these references from 2.7.4

- IronPython
- IronPython.Modules
- Microsoft.Dynamic
- Microsoft.Scripting
- Microsoft.Scripting.Metadata

I now have a problem with older C# code that creates a CodeContext object.

```
    private ScriptEngine engine;
    private PythonFunction currentFunction;

    ArrayList parameters = new ArrayList();

    LanguageContext cxt = Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.Providers.HostingHelpers.GetLanguageContext(engine);
    CodeContext context = new CodeContext(new Scope(), cxt);

    object result = currentFunction.__call__(context, parameters.ToArray());
    return result.ToString();
```

The CodeContext constructor wants a PythonDictionary and a ModuleContext as arguments, instead of what I am giving it. It looks like the API may have changed over the years. I am hoping that I am just missing the correct reference to allow this old code to compile. I know nothing about Python. Perhaps a simple code change could make this work. I could repalce the new Scope() with new PythonDictionary(), but I am not sure how to get a ModuleContext. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide more context on what you are trying to do (what comes next in your code)?

Comment: I have added a few more lines of code, but I don't think it reveals much. I have left out how the parameters are set.

Comment: What do the parameters look like? Could you dynamically invoke using [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx)? Or using `engine.Operations.Invoke(currentFunction, parameters.ToArray());`?